# How can I set gradle dependencies programatically

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy, dependency-management

How can I set gradle dependencies programatically from a file i.e 
I have this in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
  compile "org.grails:grails-core"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
  ...
}
```

and I would like to add more dependencies from a file like as below

```
[
  {env: "runtime", lib : "com.h2database:h2"},
  {env: "runtime", lib : "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29"}
 ]
```

Could someone  help me, I'm a beginner with gradle and I need a task to do it, but I don't no how to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
dependencies {

    def configFile = file('db.config.json');
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(configFile.text)
    json.each {
      "$it.env"(it.lib)
    }

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"

    ...
}
```

Comment: You are better to use `file('db.config.json')` instead of `new File('db.config.json')` so you can run `gradle` from any directory

Answer (score 5):

```
Configuration config = project.configurations.getByName('compile') 
Dependency dep = project.dependencies.create('foo:bar:1.0')
config.add(foo)
```

- [DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html)
- [ConfigurationContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html)
- [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html)